# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property must not be accessed before initialization

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

i cant figure out why im getting this error message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Typed property App\Controller\products::$ProductRepository must not be accessed before initialization in /mnt/c/mvc/src/Controller/products.php:24 Stack trace: #0 /mnt/c/mvc/index.php(21): App\Controller\products->action() #1 {main} thrown in /mnt/c/mvc/src/Controller/products.php on line 24

i hope someone can explain me why this error is thrown, thanks in advance!

ProductRepository.php

```
class ProductRepository
{
   private array $ProductList;

   public function getList(): array
   {
       $productJson = file_get_contents('model.json');

       $decodedProductList = json_decode($productJson, true);

       return explode(', ', $decodedProductList);
}
```

products.php

```
class products extends PageController
{
   private ProductRepository $ProductRepository;

   public function action(): void
   {
       $this->smarty->assign('headline', 'PRODUCTS');
       $this->smarty->assign('info', 'Product Overview');
       $this->smarty->assign('name', 'Every Product!');
       $this->smarty->assign('LIST', $this->ProductRepository->getList());

       try {
           $this->smarty->display('products.tpl');
       } catch (\SmartyException $e) {
       } catch (\Exception $e) {
       }
   }
}
```

Im trying to get an array out of a JSON File and im not sure if this is the right way to do it but my main problem is thiss error message.

I hope some of you guys can show me the direction to search in.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where do you actually set the `$ProductRepository` property? Unless you store an object in that property, you won't be able to use it as one. Type hinting it with `ProductRepository` doesn't create an actual instance.

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with set? It´s the name of the Class in wich i get the data out of my JSON File. How do i create an actual instance of it?

Comment: Have you tried the obvious choice ie. new ProductRepository() ?

Comment: You must set the `$ProductRepository` property before using it with `$this->ProductRepository`. Set the property with an instance of the ProductRepository class in the constructor seems to be the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access method `getList()` from `class ProductRepository` you need to create an object. Do this in the constructor of `class products`.

```
<?php
class products extends PageController
{
    private ProductRepository $ProductRepository;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->ProductRepository = new ProductRepository(); // you now have access to the public methods of ProductRepository
    }

    public function action(): void
    {
        $this->smarty->assign('headline', 'PRODUCTS');
        $this->smarty->assign('info', 'Product Overview');
        $this->smarty->assign('name', 'Every Product!');
        $this->smarty->assign('LIST', $this->ProductRepository->getList());

        try {
            $this->smarty->display('products.tpl');
        } catch (\SmartyException $e) {
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: maan maybe i should go to bed... Thank You!

Comment: glad I could help!